# execution of BeforeUpdate caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id

Tags: apex, custom-object, controller, class

What I'm doing wrong here? I'm creating a new record which is work_order__c and once I created I'm getting the name of the newly created row and updating the vendor__c object

`vendor__c.Current_work_order__c is a lookup on work_order__c object`

Anybody can show me what I'm doing wrong here?

> Error: Invalid Data.  Review all error messages below to correct your
>   data. Apex trigger vendorTrigger caused an unexpected exception,
>   contact your administrator: vendorTrigger: execution of AfterUpdate
>   caused by: System.StringException: Invalid id: WO-0000411:
>   Class.vendorController.PopulateWorkOrderBy: line 161, column 1

I have trigger on `vendor__c` object

```
  trigger vendorTrigger on vendor__c (after insert, after update) 
  {
    vendorController vencont = new  vendorController();
    vencont.PopulateWorkOrderBy(Trigger.new);
  }

public with sharing class vendorController
{       
      public void PopulateWorkOrderBy(List<vendor__c> vendor)
      {
         //run some business rules/validations
         //...//

         //insert into WO
         Work_Order__c wo = new Work_Order__c();
         wo.Est_Hours__c = 89;
         wo.Instructions__c = 'this is a test';
         insert wo; 

         //lets get the vendor id first:
         string venId
         for(vendor__c ven : vendor)
         {
           //get the vendor id
           venId = ven.Id;
         }

         //its time to update the vendor field
         Vendor__c vendorObj = [select Id, Name, current_work_order__c from vendor__c where id =: venId];
         vendorObj.Current_work_order__c = wo.Name //name of the newly created work_order__c Name

         //update the vendor object now
         update vendorObj;
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
vendorObj.Current_work_order__c = wo.Name;
```

To this:

```
vendorObj.Current_work_order__c = wo.Id;
```

There seem to be other problems with your code that could cause problems - I'm not sure if they are because you cut the code down or if they are real, but I'd look closely at this code:

```
string venId
for(vendor__c ven : vendor)
{
    venId = ven.Id;
}
```

This is going to save only the last vendor id - is that what you were intending?

---

**EDIT** You don't need any of the query at the end either. You need to make this a `before update, before insert trigger`

Ie, remove this:

```
Vendor__c vendorObj = [select Id, Name, current_work_order__c from vendor__c where id =: venId];
vendorObj.Current_work_order__c = wo.Name 
//update the vendor object now
update vendorObj;
```

Define your trigger like this:

```
trigger vendorTrigger on vendor__c (before insert, before update)
```

Add this:

```
vendor.Current_work_order__c = wo.Id;
```

The reason for this is that before insert/update triggers implicitly update the trigger - you are modifying the trigger before it has been saved to the database and it will be saved soon after your trigger runs.

Comment: getting this error if i changed to `wo.id` ` execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only: `

Comment: This needs to a `before update` trigger

Comment: after i changed I'm getting `execution of AfterInsert caused by: System.FinalException: Record is read-only`

Comment: 1+ Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help

Comment: No worries - good luck with the trigger.